# Codeigniter JQuery AJAX load not working in all browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to perform a simple JQuery AJAX page load within a CodeIgniter 2.x

It also seems to respond differently in different web browsers. NOTE: This is not an incorrect path issue, the pages work and display fine, I have used base_url, realurl, manually typed absolute and manually type relative paths and none give 100% success. At times I think is it the .htaccess file but if it was that it wouldn't work in all browsers not just all but 1.

**This is now working in the following browsers:**

- Chrome - Doesn't work
- IE 9 - Works
- FireFox - Works
- Safari - Works
- Opera - Works

I have placed a cleaned CI test site / application online for anyone wishing to help:
Demo (can be tested here too, try points 1,2 & 3 listed on page and watch console outputs):
http://www.allforthecode.co.uk/dev/CodeigniterJQueryAJAXTest/

**Files:**

```
/application/controllers/test.php
/application/views/test.php (loaded in by test.php)
/application/controllers/advert/test2.php (loaded in by the test.php view via JQuery ajax)
/application/controllers/test_root.php (loaded in by the test.php view via JQuery ajax)
/application/views/advert/test2.php (loaded in by test2.php)
```

**testapp/application/controllers/test.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class test extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('test');
        }

    }

?>
```

**/application/views/test.php (loaded in by test.php controller)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>JQUERY AJAX TEST</title>
        <!-- CSS START -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                font-family: arial;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            #container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 400px;
                border: 2px solid #000000;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- JS INCLUDES START -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo(base_url(" includes/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
        ")); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo(base_url(" includes/js/functions.js
        ")); ?>"></script>
        <!-- JQuery AJAX START -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadPage() {
                $url = $("#url").val();
                var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: $url,
                    data: "t=1234",
                    success: function (data) {
                        trace("#### SUCCESS ####");
                        $("#container").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        trace("#### ERROR ####");
                        trace("data = " + data);
                        traceObject(data);
                        traceToDiv("#container", "<h2>#### ERROR ####</h2>");
                        traceObjectToDiv("#container", data);
                    },
                    statusCode: function (data) {
                        trace("#### StatusCode ####");
                        traceObject(data);
                        traceToDiv("#### StatusCode ####");
                        traceObjectToDiv(data);
                    },
                    isModified: function () {
                        trace("#### isModified ####");
                    }
                });
            }
            <!-- JQuery AJAX END -->
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="frm">
            <input type="button" value="LOAD PAGE IN BOX" onclick="loadPage();" />
            <input type="reset" value="RESET" />
            <div id="container"></div>
            <b>JQuery AJAX page url target:</b>
            <input type="text" id="url" value="advert/test2"
            />
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <p>Set
                        <b>url target</b>to "test_root" to test load a root page. (WORKS IN CHROME!)</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Set
                        <b>url target</b>to "advert/test2" to test load a 1 dir deep controller page.
                        (FAILS IN CHROME!)</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Set
                        <b>url target</b>to "../ci.php" to test load a php page outside of the codeigniter
                        framework. (WORKS IN CHROME?!)</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </form>
        <br>
        <h3>Test links</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Browser test link via index.php/
                <br/>
                <a href="<? echo(base_url(" index.php/advert/test2 ")); ?>"><b><? echo(base_url("index.php/advert/test2")); ?></b></a>
            </li>
            <li>Browser test link direct (needs .htaccess to work)
                <br/>
                <a href="<? echo(base_url(" advert/test2 ")); ?>"><b><? echo(base_url("advert/test2")); ?> </b></a>
            </li>
            <li>Browser test link direct (needs .htaccess to work)
                <br/>
                <a href="<? echo(base_url(" test_root ")); ?>"><b><? echo(base_url("test_root")); ?></b></a>
            </li>
            <li>Browser test link direct
                <br/>
                <a href="../ci.php"><b>../ci.php</b></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <p>Windows 7x64 - Browser results:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Chrome - Fail</li>
            <li>IE 9.0.8112.16421 64Bit - Success (Compatability view on & off)</li>
            <li>IE 9.0.8112.16421 32Bit - Success (Compatability view on & off)</li>
            <li>FireFox 14.0.1 - Success</li>
            <li>Opera 12 build 1467 - Success</li>
            <li>Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) - Success</li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

**/application/controllers/advert/test2.php (loaded in by the test.php view via JQuery ajax)**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class test2 extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('advert/test2');
        }

    }

?>
```

**/application/views/advert/test2.php (loaded in by test2.php)**

```
Hello I am loaded by JQuery AJAX
```

**../ci.php**

```
<?
    echo("I am a php file echo test from outside of the Codeigniter test site");
?>
```

**Chromes network results are:**

```
http://127.0.0.1/testapp/public/advert/test2 - Method:POST - Status: Failed
```

**Additional**

**The only ways this code works for Chrome is**

1. If I use a html file outside the CodeIgniter framework for this project the JQuery AJAX load works. Any ideas why that would work in all other browsers bar Chrome?

and

1. If I place the page which JQuery wants to load at the root of the CodeIgniter website. So "application/controllers/test.php" which loads "application/views/advert/test2.php" will work but "application/controllers/advert/test.php" will not? But works in all other browsers? Chrome status - 0

   **Anyone got any ideas?**

Give it a try at http://www.allforthecode.co.uk/dev/CodeigniterJQueryAJAXTest/ and try points 1,2 & 3 listed on page and watch console outputs)

ZIP: http://www.allforthecode.co.uk/dev/CodeigniterJQueryAJAXTest/CodeigniterJQueryAJAXTest.zip

Comment: I just tested this with, 1 controller calling 1 view and inside that view AJAX calling another controller at codeigniters site root and it works however soon as it gets placed into a sub directory it fails. Still no resolution.

Comment: Just tested this in some different browsers giving different results are: Chrome - fails. IE - works. FireFox - fails. Safari - works. Opera - works.

Comment: I've just written my own routines for an AJAX query instead of using JQuery with a bit of debugging. IE goes from xmlHTTP.readyState 1,1,2,3,4 and xmlHTTP.status 200 before loading the page correctly. Chrome goes readyState 1,4, error on line containing the following code: xmlHttp.send(null);

Comment: Chrome will load in any controllers which are at the root of the "application/controllers" folder but none in sub folders within. So if I make a controller in "application/controllers/test.php" which calls in "application/views/advert/test2" will work. But if the controller was in a folder called "advert/test", which is the url path for the AJAX call then it would fail. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... Browser adons/plugins...

If you have adblock installed on either firefox & chrome it will break many AJAX Queries.

In my case it was "AdBlock".

Turn them off and all is fine...

Comment: Ha. Well, I guess you have somewhere to start the next time :P